# How to convert a JSON to Class - scala?

Tags: json, scala

There is a http response which is a JSON string

```
{"id":"12345","dob":"01\/01\/1991","first_name":"Joe","gender":"male"}
```

Which  needs to be instantiated into this class

```
case class UserRow(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, dob: Long, gender: String)
```

I tried parsing the JSON into a map

```
val result = parseFull(response)
println(result)
```

Output

```
Some(Map(dob -> 01/01/1991, id -> 12345, first_name -> Joe,  gender -> male))
```

Trying to get

```
map.get("id").toString().toLong //Throws a NumberFormatException
```

Dob should be converted to millis (EPOC) of type Long. Help is appreciated

Comment: Which JSON library are you using ? The answer depends largely on it.

Comment: @Andreas_neumann scala.util.parsing.json.parseFull. I dont mind using any other lib, my only criteria is performance, and my json is pretty much flat without too many nesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic Answer**
You can use https://github.com/json4s/json4s or another JSON-lib. And use a serializer.

I needed to adapt some parts of the JSON and the case class.

1. The **id** now really is a number
2. Fields that are optional (**lastName**) is not provided can be made optional by changing the type to Option in the case class
3. the names need to match exactly : **last_name** -> **lastName**
4. For handling the time in the **dob** field you could try this extension:

   // Joda Time
   implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats ++ org.json4s.ext.JodaTimeSerializers.all

*Some code examples*

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.Serialization

implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

val jsonExample = """{"id":12345,"firstName":"Joe","gender":"male"}"""

case class UserRow(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: Option[String], dob: Option[Long], gender: String)
```

*Usage Example*

```
scala>   Serialization.read[UserRow](jsonExample)
res5: UserRow = UserRow(12345,Joe,None,None,male)
```

**Extended Answer**

The JSON provided leads to several problems, that could only be solved using a handcrafted deserializer https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serialization